# Google maps v2 on android devices with minSDK below 11

Tags: android, sdk, maps, android-maps-v2

i have problem with this line when I create project which use Google maps API v2.

GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
        .getMap();

It's says that I need to set minSDK to be minimum 11, but I want to use this application also on devices with android minSDK 8 (2.3.3). Any ideas? Or simply: How I can set google maps API v2 to be compatible with devices with minSDK 8.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `SupportMapFragment` from a `FragmentActivity`, instead of `MapFragment` from an `Activity`. To use fragments on devices older than API Level 11, you need to use the Android Support package's backport of fragments (where `FragmentActivity` comes from).

Comment: What about OpenGL 2.0? Is that support on API level lower than 8?

Comment: @Mr.Hyde: AFAIK OpenGL ES 2.0 did not begin until API Level 8.

Answer (score 2):

http://android-er.blogspot.de/2012/12/using-supportmapfragment.html - small example

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

AND:

```
package de.meinprospekt.android.ui;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.map);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fragment;
    GoogleMap mMap = mapFragment.getMap();
```