# Running google maps v2 on Samsung galaxy s2 with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

im new to android programming and im trying to create an android app that loads google maps v2.

I got api key,  my code is working with no errors, i'v used some guide to write the code

But here's the problem : if im using min Sdk Version 8 my app crash and not even starts.

if im trying higher Sdk Version i cant test it because i dont have any device besides galaxy s2 and google maps v2 cant load in the emulator.

I will be glad to hear some advices.

Comment: Define "crash": post your logcat.

Comment: it is causes because for map you are using fragment and in android fregment comes after api level 8

Comment: by saying "crash" i meant that i get an error :" the application package name.. forced to stop".  how to fix the fragment for api 8?

Answer (score 0):

Use SupportMapFragment from a FragmentActivity, instead of MapFragment from an Activity. To use fragments on devices older than API Level 11, you need to use the Android Support package's backport of fragments (where FragmentActivity comes from).

http://android-er.blogspot.de/2012/12/using-supportmapfragment.html

Also Please check below step..

1. check if the "libs" folder containing the "android-support-v4.jar" exists in your project.

   "android-support-v4.jar" is located in "/extras/android/compatibility/v4/android-support-v4.jar" under your "android-sdk" drectory.
2. Before running your project, you must set your project Build target to "Google APIs", not Android x.x. version : Select your project and click Project > Properties > Project Build Target in Eclipse and select any "Google APIs ", and then run your project on your phone. If you use the emulator, also MUST set the AVD of the emulator to the any "Google APIs ".
3. Once more, you don't need to create the new Google Maps API key in order to test your project, Just use the default provided API key, which is shown as "Key for browser apps (with referers) "in your Google APIs Console.
4. Finally, the most important is to add Google Play services as an Android library project as follows:
5. Select File > Import > Android > Existing Android Code Into Workspace and click Next. Select Browse..., enter /extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib, and click Finish.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

reference link

[Google maps v2 on android devices with minSDK below 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195631/google-maps-v2-on-android-devices-with-minsdk-below-11)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I followed exactly the same steps and now i get an still the app doesnt load it says:" process  has stoped unexpectedly" when opening app. Is that impossible to load google maps on galaxy s2 or ther is another way besides google map ???

Comment: nope ... now im getting errors in the r.java files.... because i changed the project properties to api 10 :/

Answer (score 0):

Google has stop supporting android api version below 9, So if you are building new app set your min sdk level to 9.
And to test the google map you can use emulator just open sdk manager and install android latest version 4.4, build new emulator configured with android 4.4 and you can run google map in it. Hope this will help you

Comment: are you sure that you can run google maps v2 on eclipse emulator api version 9+?? I understood that google is not supporting google maps v2 on any api version emulator... am i wrong?

Comment: To test on emulator you have to create a emulator with android version 4.4 and above (i.e API 19)