# google maps api on 2.3.x

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi guys i have developer my app... but when i run my app on android 2.x crash it!
It contains Google map. On android 4.x it works fine..
Can you help me please? i don't understand this problem..
I have installed Google play service from SDK. The problem is only 2.x
Logcat:

```
    05-17 14:55:49.551: W/dalvikvm(740): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 21: Landroid/app/Activity;.getFragmentManager ()Landroid/app/FragmentManager;
05-17 14:55:49.551: D/dalvikvm(740): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0023
05-17 14:55:49.551: D/dalvikvm(740): VFY: dead code 0x0026-0030 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.showErrorDialogFragment (ILandroid/app/Activity;ILandroid/content/DialogInterface$OnCancelListener;)Z
05-17 14:55:49.565: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(740): Google Play services is missing.
05-17 14:55:49.575: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(740): Google Play services is missing.
05-17 14:55:49.581: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(740): Google Play services is missing.
05-17 14:55:49.581: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(740): Google Play services is missing.
05-17 14:55:49.581: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(740): Google Play services is missing.
05-17 14:55:49.599: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(740): Google Play services is missing.
05-17 14:55:49.605: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(740): Google Play services is missing.
05-17 14:55:49.611: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(740): Google Play services is missing.
05-17 14:55:49.611: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(740): Google Play services is missing.
05-17 14:55:49.637: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(740): Google Play services is missing.
05-17 14:55:49.647: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(740): Google Play services is missing.
05-17 14:55:49.651: D/AndroidRuntime(740): Shutting down VM
05-17 14:55:49.651: W/dalvikvm(740): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-17 14:55:49.661: E/AndroidRuntime(740): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-17 14:55:49.661: E/AndroidRuntime(740): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gianni.g/com.gianni.g.Contatti}: java.lang.NullPointerException: CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized
05-17 14:55:49.661: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-17 14:55:49.661: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-17 14:55:49.661: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-17 14:55:49.661: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-17 14:55:49.661: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-17 14:55:49.661: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-17 14:55:49.661: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-17 14:55:49.661: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 14:55:49.661: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-17 14:55:49.661: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-17 14:55:49.661: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-17 14:55:49.661: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-17 14:55:49.661: E/AndroidRuntime(740): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized
05-17 14:55:49.661: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.er.b(Unknown Source)
05-17 14:55:49.661: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory.gL(Unknown Source)
05-17 14:55:49.661: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Unknown Source)
05-17 14:55:49.661: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at com.gianni.g.Contatti.onCreate(Contatti.java:29)
05-17 14:55:49.661: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-17 14:55:49.661: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
05-17 14:55:49.661: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  ... 11 more
```

Contatti.java

```
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Contatti extends FragmentActivity{

     private final LatLng STARTING_POINT=new LatLng(x, x);

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.contatti);

         Button btnNavigator = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNavigator);

         GoogleMap map=((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
         map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(STARTING_POINT, 5));
         map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);
         map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(STARTING_POINT));

         btnNavigator.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?&daddr="+"36.997646, 14.607422";
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
                intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
         });
     }
```

contatti.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_span="6"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Telefono: +39 s"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_span="6"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=" a"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" >

            </TextView>
        </TableRow>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/GMapsBottom"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/GMapsHorizontal"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/GMapsHorizontal"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/GMapsTop" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
        </FrameLayout>     
     </TableLayout>

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/btnNavigator"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
         android:text="Avvia Navigatore" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use the same Fragment for Android >4.0 and Android <4.0 ! You have to use a Fragment from the Support v4 library and the SupportFragmentManager!

[Check this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195631/google-maps-v2-on-android-devices-with-minsdk-below-11)

Comment: Yes i use: public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
and in xml:    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
 but doesn't work

Comment: You have to post all your according files and not just these lines in order for us to be able to help you !

Answer (score 1):

From the logcat is evident what the problem is:

```
05-17 14:55:49.565: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(740): Google Play services is missing.
05-17 14:55:49.575: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(740): Google Play services is missing.
05-17 14:55:49.581: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(740): Google Play services is missing.
05-17 14:55:49.581: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(740): Google Play services is missing.
05-17 14:55:49.581: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(740): Google Play services is missing.
05-17 14:55:49.599: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(740): Google Play services is missing.
05-17 14:55:49.605: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(740): Google Play services is missing.
05-17 14:55:49.611: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(740): Google Play services is missing.
05-17 14:55:49.611: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(740): Google Play services is missing.
05-17 14:55:49.637: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(740): Google Play services is missing.
05-17 14:55:49.647: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(740): Google Play services is missing.
```

You need to make sure you have code that checks to see if [Google Play Services are installed](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#CheckServices) in the device. If they are not, you should direct the user to install them.

Comment: "you should direct the user to install them." how?